# ActiveX spreadsheet control disables workbook_open event

Tags: vba, excel, events, activex

I have inserted an ActiveX spreadsheet control into an Excel VBA form.

I have written a procedure in the ThisWorkbook.Workbook_Open() event and it will not execute upon opening the workbook when the ActiveX spreadsheet control exists on the form.

In effort to simplify the problem, I have:

- Created a new workbook.
- Added a blank form "UserForm1".
- Added an ActiveX spreadsheet control to "UserForm1", "Spreadsheet1".
- In ThisWorkbook, added the Private Workbook_Open() event:
  The Workbook_Open event does not execute when the workbook is opened.  When the spreadsheet control is deleted from the form, the workbook_open event executes normally.

Macros are enabled in both cases. Other macros execute successfully when manually called.

**How do I get the workbook_open event to execute with an ActiveX control on a VBA form?**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "Workbook_Open event has executed."
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:** When security is set to "Disable all macros with notification" and file is opened for the first time in protected view, the Workbook_Open() event is fired.  On subsequent opening of the file, the event is not fired.

Comment: Post the ThisWorkbook.Workbook_Open() event code

Comment: I added some details and the ThisWorkbook.Workbook_Open() event code.  I have tried to simplify the problem as much as possible and can't think of any other relevant details.

Comment: I am also interested to know if anyone can duplicate the behavior.